# Cannot set an environent: 'set' command not working?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I've set up a fixture on Pytest which requires a BROWSER environment to be set. However when I set it on the terminal on pycharm  on a dummy test (`set BROWSER=chrome`) Then run pytest. I get the error I raised: `Exception: tHE ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE 'BROWSER' MUST BE SET`

Fixture code:

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
import os


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def init_driver(request):
    pass

    supported_browsers = ['chrome', 'ch' , 'firefox', 'ff']

    browser = os.environ.get('BROWSER')
    if not browser:
        raise Exception("tHE ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE 'BROWSER' MUST BE SET")
    browser = browser.lower()

    if browser not in supported_browsers:
        raise Exception(f" Provided browser '{browser} is not supported"
                        f"supported_browser are : {supported_browsers}")

    if browser in ('chrome', 'ch'):
     driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    elif browser in ('firefox' , 'ff'):
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()


    request.cls.driver= driver
    yield
    driver.quit()
```

dummy test code:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("init_driver")
class Testdummy():

    def test_dumb_func(self):
        print(" i am dumb 1")
        print(" i am dumb 2")
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Tried the set command and expected it to work

Comment: `set` is how you set variables in csh, not bash or sh or zsh. Which specific shell are you using?

Comment: How do I know which shell am i using? I'm kinda new to this i don't know what the term shell is

Comment: In a POSIX system you can usually discover the current shell with `echo $0`. Most likely you have a `sh` compatible shell, such as `bash`. If so you can set the variable with `export BROWSER=chrome`.

Comment: I'm using windows 10. I tried export and it didn't work for me

Comment: If you're in Windows, and you didn't go out of your way to install something different, the shells included out-of-the-box are cmd.exe or powershell. But as a UNIX user, I don't know how to set variables -- environment or otherwise -- in either of those. It _could_ be that `set` is correct for one or both of them, but I wouldn't know.

Comment: when not set it in your test? or you want to do it in the shell?